# TableView not populating data, but JSON file is being processed

Tags: json, swift4, xcode9

I am having a problem getting my tableview to populate from my hosted JSON file. I've confirmed the app is successfully seeing the data within the JSON file, but the table itself is still blank (and oddly, shows two different vertical heights for some of the rows).

Here is my ViewController.swift:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    // var heroes = [HeroStats]()
    var bonuses = [JsonFile.JsonBonuses]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        downloadJSON {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }

        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        print("Found \(bonuses.count) rows in section.")
        return bonuses.count

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: nil)
        cell.textLabel?.text = bonuses[indexPath.row].name.capitalized
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "showDetails", sender: self)
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let destination = segue.destination as? HeroViewController {
            destination.bonus = bonuses[(tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row)!]
        }
    }

    // MARK: - Download JSON from ToH webserver
    func downloadJSON(completed: @escaping () -> ()) {
        let url = URL(string: "http://tourofhonor.com/BonusData.json")
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
            if error == nil {
                do {
                    let posts = try JSONDecoder().decode(JsonFile.self, from: data!)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        completed()
                    }
                    print(posts.bonuses.map {$0.bonusCode})
                } catch {
                    print("JSON Download Failed")
                }
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

And here is what the JsonFile.swift file looks like:

```
import Foundation

struct JsonFile: Codable {
    struct Meta: Codable {
        let fileName: String
        let version: String
    }
    struct JsonBonuses: Codable {
        let bonusCode: String
        let category: String
        let name: String
        let value: Int
        let city: String
        let state: String
        let flavor: String
        let imageName: String
    }
    let meta: Meta
    let bonuses: [JsonBonuses]
}
```

That print within the tableView numberOfSections displays 0, and I've noticed I see that printed three times, then I see the print of the codes indicating the JSON was read, then I see the "Found 0 rows in section" print again.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the datasource method you are reading from `bonuses` array. But when you are done downloading the posts you aren't assigning the bonuses of the post to your `bonuses` array.

```
func downloadJSON(completed: @escaping () -> ()) {
    let url = URL(string: "http://tourofhonor.com/BonusData.json")
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { [weak self] (data, response, error) in
        if error == nil {
            do {
                let posts = try JSONDecoder().decode(JsonFile.self, from: data!)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completed()
                }
                print(posts.bonuses.map {$0.bonusCode})
                // Here you need to assign the bonuses from your posts to your bonuses array
                // Pay attention to the [weak self] that is added in the function call
                self?.bonuses = ... // do anything that converts to bonuses
            } catch {
                print("JSON Download Failed")
            }
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

Comment: For anyone else who might find this later, the //do anything that converts to bonuses mentioned in @nayem's answer was set to `self?.bonuses = posts.bonuses` and that resolved my issue.